# Form's frame customization in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, .net, windows, command-line-interface

i'm learning C++/CLI and i was asking myself if there's any way to customize form's frame parameters such as:

- Corner radius
- Close,maximize and minimize buttons appearance and position on the actionbar
- Border color and thickness
  but i found nothing on google about this, does someone know how to do it?

The only idea i have could be to set Formborderstyle to none and drop down on the form those elements again:

- Label with custom background for the actionbar
- 3 Buttos for Close,Maximize and Minimize

But i should then re-do the listener for the label when is holded by the mouse for re-positioning, what do you think?